# Acer Aspire 1551 Will Not Wake After Suspend

Tags: 10.10, ati, suspend-resume, acer, aspire

I have an Acer Aspire 1551-5448 Netbook that is running Ubuntu 10.10 64bit Desktop.

I'm loving making the move to Ubuntu but my major stopping point is waking the laptop from a suspend/hibernate mode. When waking the computer I get a black screen. I understand this is most likely a hardware issue and would like to note that I am using the ATI drivers.

Also, I checked the `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` and everything seems normal, meaning I am not seeing any failures.

Any ideas where I should look next?

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem, it's because of ATI graphics  make sure you installed your drivers system -> administration-> additional drivers. the computer will search and refresh then install them. if you have already done this and the problem continues then go to the link, it helped me when i had the problem.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1371844

Answer (score 0):

On the blank screen try entering your password and hit enter. I had a similar issue..

Comment: Still, there has to be a way to fix this. Why else would they include the option for suspend/hibernate?

Comment: Ha, I've too had this issue. I eventually found out it was because I had previously connected an external monitor, and Ubuntu was trying to show the password dialog on that external monitor, even though it was disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

For me hitting the power button will wake up my system when its in suspend mode. Did you try that ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm having suspend issues with my Dell Inspiron 600m as well. I've found that the stock kernel in the 9.04 release works correctly with my laptop. I'm currently trying to recompile the kernel to try and pinpoint the revision that cased the error but, as of now, the only way I know how to fix this is to revert to a previous release. Have you tried versions other than 10.10?