# Acer 7551g - hibernation and suspending don't work

Tags: 10.10, suspend, hibernate, aspire

Issue is quite the same like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5881/acer-aspire-1551-will-not-wake-after-suspend), I've tried everything I found and nothing happens. If I use uswsusp, suspending works good, but graphics doesn't wake up, when I want to hibernate system, it tells me "Looking for splash system... none s2disk:snapshotting system" and nothing happens.

I'm using ATI drivers, i've tried to disable kms, unload usb3 and network drivers, still nothing. Please help me, I don't want to come back to Windows after my 2-year-relationship with Linux. I can share all files I have with you, just help me.

Comment: i have the same laptop and have the same problem..

Answer (score 1):

I justed tested the Alpha of 11.04, and suspend/resume is working perfectly :) now just need to wait for the official release so everything is nice and stable.

Comment: specifically, kernel 2.6.38 resolves this issue, so any linux distro using this kernel will have working suspend/resume (just tested with Arch linux, works great there too)

Answer (score 0):

You can update your kernel [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) and it will fix your problem.

I installed 2.6.36 months ago and my similar problems for an acer have been fixed. I can't vouch for 2.6.37 or 2.6.38 but I expect they would work as well.

Good luck.